# Trouble in install and update and upgrade in elementary os with source.list

Tags: ubuntu, installation

when i want to install or update or upgrade something in my elementary os i get this lines of error. is there a solution?

```
    Reading package lists... Error!
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com        /lin/chrome/deb/      stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists      /dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
    W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux    /chrome/deb/  stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages    )
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists    /dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the current sources.list file:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apt/sources.list
```

To automatically build a new one:

```
software-properties-gtk
```